# How to use WaitForSingleObject()

Tags: c++, multithreading

I read different topics concerning the use of `WaitForSingleObject()` but I still don't understand why I cannot make it work. 
I have a progress bar which updates using `AfxBeginThread` and I would like to wait to finish its work before doing another proccess. My code is based on this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2459/Using-AfxBeginThread-with-class-member-controlling

```
startupEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
_param->_this = this;
CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread (StartThread, _param);
WaitForSingleObject(startupEvent , INFINITE);
AfxMessageBox(_T("This message should pop up after the thread terminates."));
```

I have defined the `startupEvent` variable in the header file like this:

```
protected:
   HANDLE startupEvent;
```

Here is the thread method.

```
UINT CView::StartThread (LPVOID param)
{
   THREADSTRUCT* ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;
   ::SetEvent(ts->_this->startupEvent);
   //Some heavy calculation from here + ProgressBar update
   return 1;
}
```

In the above example, I would like the MessageBox to appear after the thread terminate the proccess but it currently appears before.

Comment: How about, maybe, calling `::SetEvent(ts->_this->startupEvent);` when the job's finished, instead of before?

Comment: I tried to call it when the job is finished but it looks it get stuck in a infinite loop (the progress bar does not update and I cannot click on the GUI anymore)

Comment: @oro777 That's because your main thread (which handles the GUI) is waiting for the thread to signal the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer to your question: you need to call `::SetEvent(ts->_this->startupEvent);`, *after* the heavy calculation, otherwise `WaitForSingleObject` will return before the heavy calculation starts.

**Side note:** you can use `WaitForSingleObject` directly on the thread handle, so you don't need an additional event. Like: `WaitForSingleObject(thread->m_hThread, INFINITE);`

**Bad practices**

Your solution contains 2 bad practices:

1. It's a bad idea to block your main-thread, because it runs the main message loop, which in turn is responsible for redrawing GUI elements (like updating the progressbar in your case). Letting the main-thread wait for a worker thread to finish defeats the reason for offloading the heavy calculation to a secondary thread.
2. Don't touch the GUI from a worker thread. The worker thread can use `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` to send status messages to the main thread, which in turn will update the UI. I found an old but still relevant [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads) about this matter.

Comment: How can I use the thread handle on WaitForSingleObject ? Is the following code correct ? WaitForSingleObject(thread->m_hThread, INFINITE); I don't understand why it blocks my main thread, you mean the AfxMessageBox ? It was just an example, in fact I am doing some GUI objects update.

Comment: OK thanks, I started my thread propject using the following tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2459/Using-AfxBeginThread-with-class-member-controlling , it seems it is not good since it updates the GUI inside the worker thread.